# Related post by category: {if id = to current page id} should not display in related post

Tags: php, wordpress

I workout wordpress related post by category.
my problem is I don't want to display the item in current post in the related post.

for example: i have list of item belong to `color category` which is `red, blue, green, black` and `red` is my current page, I don't want `red` appear in `Related post`

```
<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {$id = $category->cat_ID;} ?>

     <ul class="recentWorks">
             <?php
            if (have_posts()) : {
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            query_posts("&cat={echo $id;}&showposts=6&paged=$paged&order=ASC");
            }
            while(have_posts()) : the_post();
          ?>
          <li>
            <a class="imageHover" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnails'); ?>
            <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
          </li>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
         <?php endif; ?>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**after**

`while(have_posts()) : the_post();`

**try adding this**

```
if($post->ID == get_the_ID()) 

continue;
```

Comment: thank's but unfortunately it's not working or maybe put the new line in wrong place. `while(have_posts()) : the_post(); if($post->ID == get_the_ID()) continue;`

Comment: did you check what values did `post->ID` have and `get_the_ID() `return in each loop ?

Comment: there are no values return

Answer (score 0):

You can use arguement :-

```
'post__not_in' => array (get_the_ID())
```

which will exclude the current post from the list
Like this you can use Wp_Query()

```
$args = array(
    'cat' => '{echo $id;}',
    'post__not_in' => array (get_the_ID())
);

$query1 = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
while ( $query1->have_posts() ) {
    $query1->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
}
```

Comment: thank's but where should I insert this line in my code?

Comment: you need to use Wp_query instead of query_post. In that you can pass it as arguement

Comment: correct me if I wrong I replace `query_posts` into `Wp_query` and get this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function Wp_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mm\wp-content\themes\mm\single.php on line 22`

Comment: I have edit my answer. You can add more arguments in it. Please refer http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query